# Google calendar API using Go

Tags: go, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate Google calendar API in my Go project for the Android app. I have created the credentials, Oauth consent in Google Console. I referred this website to create event  https://jacobmartins.com/2016/03/08/practical-golang-using-google-drive-and-calendar/, but if i try to login, I am getting the following error:

> Error 400: invalid_request
>
> The loopback flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure. Follow the Loopback IP Address flow migration guide linked in the developer docs below to migrate your app to an alternative method.

Why I am getting this error? How to solve this error?

This is my redirect uri :-

```
RedirectURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/GoogleCallback",
```

This is my actual code to authorize the user!

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"net/http"

"golang.org/x/net/context"
"golang.org/x/oauth2"
"golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
"google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
)

var (
googleOauthConfig = &oauth2.Config{
    RedirectURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/GoogleCallback",
    ClientID:    "my_client_id", // from https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your-project-id>/apiui/credential
    // ClientSecret: os.Getenv("googlesecret"), // from https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your-project-id>/apiui/credential
    Scopes:   []string{calendar.CalendarScope},
    Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
}
// Some random string, random for each request
oauthStateString = "random"
)

const htmlIndex = `<html><body>
<a href="/GoogleLogin">Log in with Google</a>
</body></html>`

func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", handleMain)
http.HandleFunc("/GoogleLogin", handleGoogleLogin)
http.HandleFunc("/GoogleCallback", handleGoogleCallback)
fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
func handleMain(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
fmt.Fprintf(w, htmlIndex)
}

func handleGoogleLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
url := googleOauthConfig.AuthCodeURL(oauthStateString)
http.Redirect(w, r, url, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}

func handleGoogleCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
state := r.FormValue("state")
if state != oauthStateString {
    fmt.Printf("invalid oauth state, expected '%s', got '%s'\n", oauthStateString, state)
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    return
}

code := r.FormValue("code")
token, err := googleOauthConfig.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("oauthConf.Exchange() failed with '%s'\n", err)
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    return
}

oauth2.NewClient(context.Background(), oauth2.StaticTokenSource(token))
}
```

Comment: You cannot use 127.0.0.1 as the callback address. You have to use the public IP address of your machine, or some proxy in front of your machine.

Comment: Can you please tell me. How to get public ip address in my system, I am using linux